# Start application from another activity when logged in

Tags: android, android-activity

My app starts with a log in activity and after user logs in, it redirects to `MainActivity`. The point is, I want to start the app from `MainActivity` when the user has already logged in. And Also I want to pressing back from `MainActivity` doesn't redirect to `LoginActivity`. I store the log in status in shared prefrences.
For more clarity:
Launcher -> LoginActivity -> MainActivity ---- // when not logged in
Launcher -> MainActivity                  ---- // when logged in
MainActivity --(pressing back button)--> Launcher

I've searched the web and SO question since this is a straight forward question but seems I don't know the correct phrase to search. Please help me out.

Comment: Use sharedpreferences to store the data once you logged in (it may be user id or name whatever its you want), in your launcher check the preference value, if its not equal to null, redirect it to your corresponding activity, if it is null means redirect the user to Login Activity.

Comment: in the loginactivity oncreate before setcontentview check the login status if it is true start mainactivity and finish loginactivity in onstop of loginactivity

Comment: Store a flag in shared preference that the user is logged in or not...Then put a if statement in Launcher to check is logged in then redirect to MainActivity else redirect to Login Activity...... When Going from LoginActivity to MainActivity Finish the Login Activity Class so that on Back pressed it would return to Launcher from MainActivity.....

Comment: How I can check the flag in Launcher? Launcher isn't in my app. By launcher I mean xperia launcher/Go launcher and like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Launcher -> LoginActivity -> MainActivity ---- // when not logged in
>
> Launcher -> MainActivity ---- // when logged in

You cannot change the launcher behaviour in this way.

To achieve what you want to do simply check if the user is logged in or not in the `onCreate(...)` method of the `LoginActivity`. If the user is logged in than do the following...

```
startActivity(this, MainActivity.class);
finish();
```

If the user is not logged in then do what you need to do to log the user in then call the above code.

Answer (score 3):

For bypassing LoginActivity and going to Launcher onBackPressed after your Login to MainActivity, put no history inside your manifest to your LoginActivity

```
<activity
    android:name="com.your.package.LoginActivity"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```

Use `SharedPreferences` to check if logged in or not.

You can set the string on login:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
editor.putString("login", "yes");
editor.commit();
```

You can check login value by loading from SharedPreferences like this:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    // "login","no" means default string value is "no", so if you didn't set yes after login, it will be no as default
    if(preferences.getString("login", "no").equals("yes")){
         //login value is yes, so start mainactivity
    }
    else{
        //login value is no, so start loginactivity
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a splash screen as your launcher activity which will decide which  screen to launch.
i.e if logged in go to mainactivity if not then loginactivity .
Both mainactivity & login activity will have splash screen as your parent activity.